# Split a 32 bit Integer into 4 8 bit Integers

Tags: java, video, video-processing

I am working with video data in Java and wish to store four 8 bit integers in a 32 bit Integer. In other words I would like to pack the R, G, B, and A values from 0 to 255 into a single 32 bit Integer.

How can I go about:

1. Creating 4 Integer values from 0 to 255 and store them in a 32 bit Integer?
2. Unpacking the 4 8 bit Integer values from the 32 bit Integer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Packing:

```
int rgba = (a << 24) | (b << 16) | (g << 8) | r;
```

`<<` is the left shift operator; `|` is the bitwise or operator.

Unpacking:

```
int r = rgba & 0xff;
int g = (rgba >> 8) & 0xff;
int b = (rgba >> 16) & 0xff;
int a = (rgba >> 24) & 0xff;
```

`>>` is the (signed *) right shift operator; `&` is the bitwise and operator.

Obviously, you can pack/unpack them in any order you desire.

---

(*) You can use either the signed or unsigned (`>>>`) right shift here. It makes no difference to the result in this case.

Answer (score 0):

That’s simple. Use the `Color` class.

> 1. Creating 4 Integer values from 0 to 255 and store them in a 32 bit Integer?

Use the `Color(int, int, int, int)` constructor and the `getRGB` method.

> 2. Unpacking the 4 8 bit Integer values from the 32 bit Integer?

Use the `Color(int)` constructor and the methods `getRed`, `getGreen`, `getBlue` and `getAlpha`.

**Link:** [Documentation of the `java.awt.Color` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following utilities based of [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html):

```
    int transformToInt(byte[] array) {
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(array).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getInt();
    }

    byte[] transformToBytes(int value) {
        return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(value).array();
    }
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a56210680)